# using content manager versus irepository in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

Can someone please share thoughts on what's the difference between contentmanager and irepository in orchard cms? And when using a content manager is better than irepository? When using irepository is better? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content manager deals with content items, whereas IRepository is a lower level API that deals with records. Records are typically, but not necessarily associated with parts, but there are parts that don't have a record.

In general, you should use content manager. If you don't have a really good reason to use IRepository, don't. The API is mostly there to allow content manager to figure out how to query over arbitrary parts, and should almost never be directly used.